# variables is brackets ()

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, returndata

What's the meaning of the code, wherein the return values of a function are stored in variables which are initialized inside brackets, like the following:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = _contract.delegatecall(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("setVars(uint256)", _num)
    );


(bool success, ) = address(parentContract).call{value:msg.value}(abi.encodeWithSignature("initiatePayment(uint256)", index));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you are wondering what `(bool success, bytes memory data)` are.

In Solidity, a `call` (or `delegatecall`) returns two values that describe the status and result of the call. The first return value is a `bool` that states whether a call was successful or unsuccessful. The second parameter is the return data of the call, usually labeled `data` or `res`. This represents any data returned by the `call`.

You can read more about `call`s in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=delegatecall#members-of-address-types).

**Edit based on comment**

In your second example, only the `bool` is stored. This is common if the calling contract does not need or care about the returned value but does care about whether or not the `call` succeeded.

Comment: thanks. So, in the 2nd example, `(bool success, )` means we are storing only the first return value, right?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Shane's good answer:

In Python and other languages this variable type is called a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp).

In Solidity they're not considered a proper type, but can be used as a shorthand. See the docs: [Destructuring Assignments and Returning Multiple Values](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/control-structures.html?highlight=tuples#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values)